# Mediawiki audit trail/history

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Need to hide audit trail/history for not login users. But it should visible to login user.

It get hide after making entry in MediaWiki:Common.css file.

```css
#ca-history { display:none!important; }
```

As per requirement it should remain available for user who has logined.

Comment: MediaWiki does not have a separate permission for accessing the page history. You can make cosmetic changes but don't expect them to prevent a motivated anonymous user from accessing the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is correct: Make the history invisible to all users. The next step is to show it to all registered users by creating the `MediaWiki:Group-user.css` page with the following rule:

```css
#ca-history {
  display: block !important;
}
```

See [the page on en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Group-user.css).